# convert hexadecimal to binary -- java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert from hexadecimal to binary. I already have the code down for the decimal conversion to binary, just don't know how to go from there and convert to binary.

```
public static String hexToDec(String valueIn) {
    int endNum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < valueIn.length(); i++) {         
        char curDigit = valueIn.charAt(i);
        endNum *= 16;     

        if (curDigit >= 'A' && curDigit <= 'F')      
            endNum += 10 + (curDigit - 'A');
        else 
            endNum += curDigit - '0';
    }
    return "" + endNum;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the decimal number: ");
    String valueIn = keyboard.nextLine ();
    String outputOut = hexToDec(valueIn);
    System.out.println("The output is: " + outputOut);    
}

public static String decimalToBinary(int valueIn) {
    int remainder, i = 0;
    String binaryNum = "";
    while (valueIn != 0) {
        remainder = valueIn % 2;
        valueIn /= 2;
        binaryNum = remainder+binaryNum;
    }
    return binaryNum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the decimal number: ");
    int valueIn = keyboard.nextInt ();
    String outputOut = decimalToBinary(valueIn);
    System.out.println("The output is: " + outputOut);    
}
```

Comment: how about decimal to binary?

Comment: @ScaryWombat i have the code for that too, i'll update it right now

Comment: Hex -> Decimal -> Binary - looks like you have all you need

Comment: i do get that, i'm just a bit stumped on how specifically to do it

Comment: The direct step from hex to binary is much easier than going via decimal in between. Every hex digit corresponds to 4 bits.

Comment: In other words, @ScaryWombat is suggesting method nesting `decimalToBinary(hexToDec(hexValueHere))`

Comment: @Kartik Yep, Might need to convert the String to an Int first

Comment: `decimalToBinary(Integer.parseInt(hexToDec(hexValueHere)))` should do it

Comment: @makaylahwilson did you try my answer, did it help you?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply define your own mapping and skip the decimal conversion route altogether as per comments.

```
HashMap<char, String> mapping = new HashMap<char, String>();
mapping.put('0', "0000" );
mapping.put('1', "0001" );
mapping.put('2', "0010");
mapping.put('3', "0011");
mapping.put('4', "0100" );
mapping.put('5', "0101");
mapping.put('6', "0110");
mapping.put('7', "0111");
mapping.put('8', "1000");
mapping.put('9', "1001");
mapping.put('a', "1010");
mapping.put('b', "1011");
mapping.put('c', "1100");
mapping.put('d', "1101");
mapping.put('e', "1110");
mapping.put('f', "1111");
```

Then can do this:

```
String hexValue = "something";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : hexValue) {
    // need to do some error checking here.
    result.append(mapping[Character.toLowerCase(c)]);
}

System.out.prinltn(result.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't want to break in between your current approach, I'd say from seeing the comments, that to convert decimal to binary, all you have to do is get the modulus of the number again and again, and then combine those all in reverse order to get your binary number.

This would be a bit longer approach, so I'd say you may take inspiration from the codes below.

`BigInteger.toString(radix)` will do what you want. Just pass in a radix of 2. Read more about that [here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

```java
static String hexToBin(String s) {
  return new BigInteger(s, 16).toString(2);
}
```

`BigInteger` ensures that the large numbers get no problem during conversion, but you may also use this code below, this simple does mark you understand the conversion a bit more better.

```java
String hexToBinary(String hex) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    return bin;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As an example.

**What is 4B5 (Hexadecimal)?**

- The "4" is in the "16×16" position, so that means 4 ×16×16
- The "B" (11) is in the "16" position, so that means 11 ×16
- The "5" is in the "1" position so that means 5.

**Answer:** 4B5 = 4×16×16 + 11×16 + 5 (=1205) in Decimal

Then convert the decimal number to binary number.

**How to convert decimal to binary**

Conversion steps:

- Divide the number by 2.
- Get the integer quotient for the next iteration.
- Get the remainder for the binary digit.
- Repeat the steps until the quotient is equal to 0.

`(1205) in Decimal= (10010110101) in Binary.`

Try to implement this .